# What is the difference between (void*) and (void(*)(argument type)) cast?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
void funcPtr(int a);

int main(){
   int k=1;
   void (*funcPtr2)(int);

   funcPtr2 = (void*)(funcPtr);
   // funcPtr2 = (void(*)(int))(funcPtr);

   (*funcPtr2)(k);
   return 0;
}

void funcPtr(int a){
   printf("%d", a);
}
```

What is the difference between `(void*)` and `(void(*)(argument type)` in function pointer type casting?

As a result, it does not occur warning.

Is this wrong?  about `(void*)` type casting

Comment: `error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'void (*)(int)'`

Comment: Why would one cast in the first place. The function pointer and addressed function *match* ? And you're partially correct; there is no warning, [its a flat-out-error](http://ideone.com/8BpCPx)

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_.

Comment: `void *handle;  *(void **)(&funcPtr2) = dlsym(handle, "my_function");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this wrong? about (void*) type casting

Yes, it is.

C standard doesn't allow a conversion of a function pointer to an object pointer or assignment between them. If you up your compiler warning level, you may get warnings/errors such as compiling with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c11 file.c
```

I am not sure why you thought about casting a function pointer. Provided the function pointer type matches the function, simply assign it:

```
 funcPtr2 = funcPtr;
```

---

Aside:

You can use the function pointer just like a function:

```
 funcPtr2(k);
```

and use a standard prototype for `main` such as:

```
int main(void)
```

Comment: The restriction to disallow code <-> data pointer conversion dates back to the days of the Intel Memory Model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model) and probably similar contraptions on other architectures. E.g. under the "medium" model, `sizeof(void *) == 2`, but `sizeof(void(*)(void)) == 4`, making to and from conversions unsafe. Of course, none of these platforms and memory models have any relevance regarding POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with `dlsym`, declared  `void *dlsym(void *restrict handle, const char *restrict name)`. `dlsym` returns a pointer to a function named `name` defined in and accessible through `handle`.
However, as @BlueMoon states, this is not defined in ISO C and `gcc` indeed complains if made pedantic. POSIX tried to address that and required conforming implementation to make that cast well-defined in its indefiniteness.

From [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

> Note that conversion from a void * pointer to a function pointer as in:
>
> `fptr = (int (*)(int))dlsym(handle, "my_function");`
>
> is not defined by the ISO C standard. This standard requires this  conversion to work correctly on conforming implementations.

Another way to make that cast conforming is to first convert the function pointer to `void**` and then dereference it. This should be well-defined.
In your case,

```
void funcPtr(int a); /* symbol to extract */

int main(void)
{
     void (*fn)(int);
     *(void**)(&fn) = dlsym(your_handle, "funcPtr");


     fn(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(void*)
```

casts a pointer to a *pointer to void*, or a generic pointer.

```
void(*)(int)
```

is a function pointer to a function taking an int argument and returning nothing.

```
int fn(float f) { return f * 3.14; }

void* ptr = fn;
```

Would make `ptr` the address of the first machine instruction of `fn` but not allow you to use it.

```
int(*ptr)(float) = fn;
// or
typedef int(FnPtr)(float);
FnPtr* ptr = fn;
```

takes the address in a way that the compiler knows what kind of function call is being pointed to so that you can call the function

```
int n = ptr(2.5);
```

Which can be useful for doing something like

```
void get_data(int socket, int timeout, void(*callback)(char*, size_t));
```

Which is a function I can pass another function to.

```
void recv_data(char* data, size_t len)
{
    ...
}

...

get_data(socket, 60, recv_data);
```

Comment: In C, you cannot cast a function pointer to `void*`.

Comment: @undur_gongor Some compilers allow it at certain warning levels, and I'm doing this on my kindle, so I chose not to argue that case.

Comment: (But that was why i choose `would `)